# unit testing a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing

I have a component that looks like this,

```
<template>
<!-- eslint-disable vue/no-v-html -->
<div class="c-dialog" :class="{'u-block': show}" @triggerOpen="handleOpen">
    <div class="c-dialog__background" @click="handleClose">
        <div class="c-dialog__wrapper u-mt-4 u-mb-1">
            <div class="c-dialog__action u-flex">
                <button class="c-dialog__close u-bg-denim-blue u-border-0 u-text-white" @click="handleClose">Close</button>
            </div>
            <div class="c-dialog__main u-px-2 u-py-4 u-border u-bg-white">
                <h4>{{ content.title }}</h4>
                <div class="c-dialog__content u-mt-2" v-html="content.content" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am wanting to unit test it, but I am very rusty when it comes to unit testing, the component is very simple, it is either show or hidden based on data value (show: true/false).

I assume that I would need 1 test for asserting that the component is hidden when show = false and another for asserting that modal is visible when show = true. But in a component that is so simple should I be unit testing anything else? There are 2 methods in the component `handleClose` (sets show to false) and handleOpen (sets show to true), does these methods need there own tests also? So far my test looks like,

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Dialog from './Dialog.vue'

test('Dialog', () => {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should test the open / close state.

You can also use `jest.spy` to see if the correct methods are called, but in this case testing the result should be fine.

The `v-html` is also something you could consider testing.

The [snapshot tests](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing) are real nice to see if the state changes correctly, and it's implicitly testing your class assignment to.

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Dialog from './Dialog.vue'

function mountWith() {
  return shallowMount(Dialog, {
    data() {
      return {
        open: false,
        ...data
      }
    }
  });
}

describe('Dialog', () => {
  let wrapper;

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.destroy()
  })

  it('should mount successfully', () => {
    wrapper = mountWith()
    
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)
  });
  
  it('should match snapshot in initial state', () => {
    wrapper = mountWith()
    
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
  });
  
  it('should match snapshot while open', () => {
    wrapper = mountWith({ open: true })
    
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
  });

  it('should open on c-dialog click', async () => {
    wrapper = mountWith()
    wrapper.find('.c-dialog').trigger('click');
    await Vue.nextTick()

    expect(wrapper.vm.open).toBe(true)
  });
  
  it('should close on background click ', async () => {
    wrapper = mountWith({ open: true })
    wrapper.find('.c-dialog__background').trigger('click');
    await Vue.nextTick()

    expect(wrapper.vm.open).toBe(false)
  });

  it('should close on dialog close click ', async () => {
    wrapper = mountWith({ open: true })
    wrapper.find('.c-dialog__close').trigger('click');
    await Vue.nextTick()

    expect(wrapper.vm.open).toBe(false)
  });  
});
```